# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState on showing a Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

i am just trying to showing a Dialog fragment. when i showing a dialog fragment i am getting the below crash. and i can't able to reproduce this issue but users were keep on reporting.

Can you please explain me how to reproduce this issue and a method to solve it. i have tried some of the solutions from stack overflow. but it doesn't help me.

```
    DialogInit dialogInit= new DialogInit ();
    dialogInit.show(mActivity.getFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
```

Crash

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1428)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1446)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:687)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:663)
        at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:230)
        at com.example.app.run(DialogInit.java:157)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: could you please post the entire Activity/Fragment where you try to show the Dialog?